# creating new file whose name only differs by case from existing file with matlab/octave fopen

Tags: matlab, file, octave, fopen

Is it possible to use fopen in MATLAB or Octave to create a file with a name that only differs by case from an existing file? In MATLAB R2016a and Octave 4.2.0 on MacOS 10.11.6, the following code only creates `FooBar.txt` and writes `bar` to it (`foobar.txt` is not created):

```
fid = fopen('FooBar.txt', 'w');
fwrite(fid, 'foo', 'char');
fclose(fid);
fid = fopen('foobar.txt', 'w');
fwrite(fid, 'bar', 'char');
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: You can't. The default OSX file format is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB can do that, but only on Linux. By default, Windows and MacOS do not respect case.

NTFS and FAT (and variants) are [case sensitive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100625) (for POSIX compliance), but the Windows kernel does not respect case. Meaning, in principle NTFS can hold two files with a name that differs only in case, but those files can not be created nor differentiated by Windows, unless you do system calls on a much lower level than is common in most programs (read: "hack").

HFS+ on MacOS infamously [is case-insensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Limitations). Meaning, although the MacOS kernel could handle it in principle, the file system cannot. Currently used in MacOS Sierra (10.12), [the experimental APFS is case sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Support), but I believe system-wide support for it is disabled (...although I could be wrong here). Although [it can be enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112772/how-do-i-set-my-hd-to-be-case-sensitive), I believe case sensitivity does not align with Apple's design philosophies (plus, many apps explicitly assume case *in*sensitivity and will break if that changes), so I think it more than likely that enabling support for case sensitivity will grow progressively harder in future version.